# Display part of URL on a page (i.e. Instagram Access Token)?

Tags: javascript, php, instagram

What I'm trying to achieve is when a user authenticates with Instagram, and they're redirected to a page like "http://domainnamehere./instagram#access_token=27744335.fcaef44.a95s9e741f3c4ea7bcad21d80809ca40"

To be able to print the "27744335.fcaef44.a95s9e741f3c4ea7bcad21d80809ca40" string on a part of the web page, i.e. 
    `<p>Here is your access token: ________</p>`

I know how to print the whole URL using javascript, using this:
    `<h3 id="right">`
    `<script type="text/javascript">`
    `document.write(location.href);`
    `</script>`
    `</h3>`

But how can I set it up to get only part of the URL?

Exactly what I'm trying to achieve can be seen here live http://theultralinx.com/instagram (click "setup instagram," authenticate, and then the next page shows the access token.

Thank you!

Comment: Did any answer work for you? If so, please, accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can still look for an URI parser, but it might be obtained using basic string functions like `indexOf` and `substring` as follows:

```
var uri = "http://domainnamehere./instagram#access_token=27744335.fcaef44.a95s9e741f3c4ea7bcad21d80809ca40";

var indexOfHashVar = uri.indexOf("access_token=");
// 13 is the number of characters of "access_token="
var token = uri.substring(indexOfHashVar + 13);
console.log(token);
```

As @PhistucK suggested in some comment, you might get the hash part of the whole uri using `window.location.hash`, thus my sample may be altered in the first line with:

```
var uri = window.location.hash;
```

Comment: It would be a bit more performant and easier to use `document.location.hash` instead of the entire URL.

Comment: @PhistucK You're right, but I was just showing how to extract a part of a generic string instead... Now I don't have time to put your idea in my question, you can edit it or I'll do in few hours :) Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Never use `document.write`, it is discouraged.
This should work.

HTML -

```
<p>Here is your access token: <span id="access-token"></span></p>
```

JavaScript -

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
 // Getting the part of the URL that starts with #.
 var hash = document.location.hash,
     // Storing the string for which we search in the hash.
     accessTokenParameter = "access_token=";
 // Setting the found value as the content of the access-token element we created
 // above by taking the part of the hash (substring) that begins after the
 // parameter by getting the index of the character (indexOf) with which the
 // parameter name starts and adding the length of the parameter name (and =)
 // in order to get past the name and start from the value.
 document.getElementById("access-token").innerHTML =
  hash.substring(hash.indexOf(accessTokenParameter) +
   accessTokenParameter.length);
}, false);
```

In order to support Internet Explorer as well, you can use `window.onload =` or name the function and use `window.attachEvent` after feature detecting it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for adding the comments and explaining how it works. When I tried this though, my browser told me there was an error on the last line. "ReferenceError: Left side of assignment is not a reference."

Comment: Sorry! You are right, I forgot to add `.innerHTML`. Fixed.

Comment: Hi, now I'm getting: 
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("access-token").innerHTML = hash.substring(hash.indexOf(accessTokenParameter) + accessTokenParameter.length)')

Comment: Did you use the HTML I wrote? It has an element that has this "access-token" ID.

Comment: Yes I did. I added the javascript in-line... let me try it in the head? Edit: Tried it in the head, still no dice. That's the error safari's debug log is showing me. I'm using the `<span id="access-token"></span>` wrapped within paragraph tags.

Comment: No, the script must be included after the `<span>` (or the `</p>`). Or it can be run on load. I will change the code. And never use inline scripts. Put the JavaScript in its own file and reference it using `<script src="path/to/js/file"></script>`.

Comment: He can use `document.write` if he pleases.

Comment: @RPM - yes, he can, but it is a very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3 id="right">
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(window.location.hash.split("access_token=")[1]);  </script>
</h3>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this

```
<h3 id="right">  <script type="text/javascript"> var href = location.href; href = href.replace("http://domainnamehere./instagram#access_token=","");  document.write(href);  </script>  </h3>
```

Comment: The slightest change can ruin this, for example, dropping the `www` (which works in most cases) from the URL.

Comment: This works! Only thing is I have to make a new redirect page. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

if ur link is always like the link in the question (same domain & no other variables) u can use this:

```
var url =location.href ;
var res = url.slice(45);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: The slightest change can ruin this, for example, dropping the `www` (which works in most cases) from the URL.

Comment: this is url after redirect & uses a developer given url not typed url

Comment: Give me a good reason not to use `document.location.hash` instead?

Comment: he asked for answer & i told him about the way i know & it works
no force to use this way & no need to give u a reason to use this way instead of  `document.location.hash`

Comment: Frankly, I just wrote the reason for my down vote, out of courtesy. Do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Also - `url.slice` (well, `String.prototype.slice`) does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and below.